# UltraWebGrid: How to use a drop-down list in a column

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I'm using the Infragistics grid and I'm having a difficult time using a drop-down list as the value selector for one of my columns.

I tried reading the documentation but Infragistics' documentation is not so good. I've also taken a look at this [discussion](http://news.infragistics.com/forums/p/9063/45792.aspx) with no luck.

What I'm doing so far:

```
col.Type = ColumnType.DropDownList;
col.DataType = "System.String";

col.ValueList = myValueList;
```

where `myValueList` is:

```
ValueList myValueList = new ValueList();

myValueList.Prompt = "My text prompt";
myValueList.DisplayStyle = ValueListDisplayStyle.DisplayText;

foreach(MyObjectType item in MyObjectTypeCollection)
{
    myValueList.ValueItems.Add(item.ID, item.Text); // Note that the ID is a string (not my design)
}
```

When I look at the page, I expect to see a drop-down list in the cells for this column, but my columns are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what was wrong.

The column must allow updates.

```
uwgMyGrid.Columns.FromKey("colTest").AllowUpdate = AllowUpdate.Yes;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from one of my pages:

```
UltraWebGrid uwgMyGrid = new UltraWebGrid();
uwgMyGrid.Columns.Add("colTest", "Test Dropdown");
uwgMyGrid.Columns.FromKey("colTest").Type = ColumnType.DropDownList;
uwgMyGrid.Columns.FromKey("colTest").ValueList.ValueListItems.Insert(0, "ONE", "Choice 1");
uwgMyGrid.Columns.FromKey("colTest").ValueList.ValueListItems.Insert(1, "TWO", "Choice 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void MakeCellValueListDropDownList(UltraWebGrid grid, string columnName, string valueListName, string[] listArray)
    {
        //Set the column to be a dropdownlist
        UltraGridColumn Col = grid.Columns.FromKey(columnName);            
        Col.Type = ColumnType.DropDownList;
        Col.DataType = "System.String";

        try
        {
            ValueList ValList = grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns.FromKey(columnName).ValueList;
            ValList.DataSource = listArray;
            foreach (string item in listArray)
            {
                ValList.ValueListItems.Add(item);
            }
            ValList.DataBind();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {

        }
    }
```